# Remove some commas from "ModernCV"

Tags: moderncv, punctuation

You can see in this picture (made by ModernCV ) that the commas appear automatically between fields

[image]

I would like to remove some commas without changing the definition of this macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commas are hard-coded within the `\cventry` macro; here's the definition (from [`moderncvbodyi.sty`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/moderncvbodyi.sty)):

```
\renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{%
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
    {\bfseries#3}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}%
    .\strut%
    \ifx&#7&%
    \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#7\end{minipage}}\fi}}
```

If arguments are not left blank, commas are inserted before displaying another argument. You should either change this definition within your preamble, or fool `\cventry` by formatting components manually within other arguments:

[image]

```
\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}  % default
\cventry{year--year}{Degree {\mdseries\itshape Institution}}{}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution \textup{City}}{}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City \textit{Grade}}{}{Description}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following command.

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd\cventry{,}{}{}{}
```